# Finding if the two DateTime is within a week

Tags: c#, date, datetime

I wanted to find if two `DateTime` are within a week.
One of them is the current system `Datetime`, which I got it by using:

```
DateTime CurrentDateTime = new DateTime();
CurrentDateTime = DateTime.Now;
```

The other `DateTime` will just be a selected date. Assuming it is stored in a variable called : `ExportDate`.

So, I can find the difference between them by doing

```
ExportDate.Subtract(CurrentDateTime)
```

But I cannot change this value into a int for comparing...
So how should I compare this to `DateTime` to see if this two dates are greater then 0Days, and less then 7Days.

Comment: OT you are letting the computer do too much work: first assinging `new DateTime()` then immediately overwriting with `DateTime.Now`. Skip the first assignment and/or combine the two lines.

Comment: Do you want "within 7 days" or "within the same week"? As an example: would "thusday" and the "next monday" be a match?

Answer (score 1):

Subtracting two datetimes gives you a TimeSpan. This class comes with a property called TotalDays.

> Gets the value of the current TimeSpan structure expressed in whole and fractional days.

Src: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-Us/library/system.timespan(v=vs.110).aspx

You can use to count the number of days I guess.

Regards,
Seb

Answer (score 1):

Try to compare the `TotalDays` of the resulting `TimeSpan`. Depending on which is later, the result must be between -7 and 7. Use `Math.Abs` to avoid comparing the value against both bounds:

```
bool isWithinWeek = Math.Abs(ExportDate - CurrentDate).TotalDays) < 7
```

If the time of day is irrelevant, compare only the dates:

```
bool isWithinWeek = Math.Abs(ExportDate.Date - CurrentDate.Date).TotalDays) < 7
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
(ExportDate - CurrentDateTime).TotalDays <= 7
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the DayOfYear property of DateTime to get the day in the year and then check if the difference is less than 7 or not. You can try:

```
bool isWithinAWeek = Math.Abs(currentDateTime.DayOfYear-exportDate.DayOfYear)>7?false:true;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you do it in PHP

```
function isTwoDatesWithinTheSameWeek($date1, $date2){
    $d1 = strtotime($date1); //"2015-01-01"
    $d2 = strtotime($date2); //"2016-01-05"

     $d1w = date("W", $d1);
     $d2w = date("W", $d2);

     return $d1w === $d2w;
}
```